# Checking if the api is down from angular client application

Tags: angular

I am having an angular 8 application which pulls data from .Net code web api application. I need to check if the API is down and then redirect
to the system maintenance page.
I have currently written a method that will call an endpoint to see if the service is available and subscribing to that method which checks
every 10 seconds. Is that the best way of doing it

ConnectionService

```
@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private configurationService: ConfigurationService) { }
    checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable() {
        var pingUrl = this.configurationService.baseUrl + "/api/online";
        return this.httpClient.get(pingUrl);
    }
}
```

OfflineComponent

```
@Component({
    selector: 'not-found',
    templateUrl: './offline.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./offline.component.css'],
    animations: [fadeInOut]
})
export class OfflineComponent implements OnInit {
    subscription: Subscription;
    pingInterval: number;
    constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
        // Check if Core-API service is Online or Offline
        this.pingInterval = environment.corePingIntervalSeconds;
        const source = interval(this.pingInterval*1000);
        this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => 
            {
                this.opensnack();
                console.log(val);
            });   
    }
```

Comment: Spamming requests is basically never a good idea. You could think about opening a websocket to the server and handle the connection lost event.

Comment: Do you really have to check every 5 seconds?

Comment: Basically the requirement is that the application should poll to see if the api is still available and without user actions. Just to correct it is 10 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of checking for the server availability is totally fine. You are missing the call to your service. I think this refactor will get you there. [Here is a Stackblitz with working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ping-server-observable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), I pinged google but you get the idea:

```
      import { first } from "rxjs/operators";

      export class OfflineComponent implements OnInit {

        private source = interval(
           environment.corePingIntervalSeconds * 1000;
        );

        constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {

          this.source.subscribe(() => {
             this.connectionService
            .checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(resp => {
              if (resp.status === 200 ) {
                console.log(true)
              } else {
                console.log(false)
              }
            }, err => console.log(err));
          });
        }
...
```

Comment: Sorry i missed the code that calls the service. The logic was written in this.opensnack() method. My question is this the best way of doing it

Comment: Yes. You could write a socket enpoint, but if you need to get it done this way is perfectly fine, and requires less boiler... besides, you dont add the socket server to maintain.

Comment: Just remember to unsubscribe from source !! ;)

Comment: Any particular reason why you used  .pipe(first())

Comment: Yes, because we definitely want to unsubscribe as soon as we get the response. So by the time the new ping req emits we have only one subscription at a time.

Comment: Ok. I am getting compile error Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Object

Comment: You need to add { observe: 'response' } to your http.get request.. .it should look something like this:  return this.httpClient.get(pingUrl,  { observe: 'response' }); This will return the whole object.